# Sticky/Moving navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been using [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp) to create a navbar. What I want to achieve is a little bit different and I am struggling to make it work.

I am trying to create a navigation bar which is fixed to bottom of the page and while scrolling the content, it gradually goes up and after it reaches the top it is fixed there and when you continue to scroll further it stays fixed to the top.

What is the best solution to create such a navigation?

Thanks for your help.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};



var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;



function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
body{line-height:1;font-family:arial}
h1{font-size:25px}
h2{font-size:21px}
h3{font-size:18px}
h4{font-size:16px}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}
nav ul{list-style:none}
blockquote,q{quotes:none}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}
a{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
ins{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;text-decoration:none}
mark{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold}
del{text-decoration:line-through}
abbr[title],dfn[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin:1em 0;padding:0}
input,select{vertical-align:middle}
body,html{background-color:#FFF}
nav{display:inline-block}
nav ul li a{background:#fff;padding:2px 6px;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;color:#344;border-radius:5px}
nav ul li a:hover{color:#000}
nav ul li{display:inline-block;margin:10px}
nav ul{list-style:none}
article{border-bottom:2px dotted #998;padding-bottom:20px;margin-bottom:20px}
article h2{font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:12px}
footer{background:#344;max-width:1000px;margin:0 -20px;clear:both;text-align:right}
footer p{padding:20px;color:#FFF}
address{padding:10px 20px 30px 10px}
aside > div{margin:10px auto;background:#344;min-height:150px;padding:30px 10px;text-align:center;color:#FFF}
a#logo{font-size:40px;color:#344;font-weight:bold;display:block;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;line-height:40px;padding:60px 5px}
body > section{max-width:1000px;margin:auto;padding:30px 0px;border-bottom:1px solid #999;color:#333}
#navbar {position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%;overflow: hidden;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
#navbar a {float: left;display: block;color: #000;text-align: center;padding: 14px 16px;text-decoration: none;font-size: 17px;background-color: #FFF;z-index: 1;}
#navbar a:hover {background-color: #ddd;color: black;}
#navbar a.active {background-color: #A9A9A9;color: white;}
.content {padding: 16px;}
.sticky {position: fixed;top: 0;width: 100%;}
.sticky + .content { padding-bottom: 60px;}
footer a{color:#FFF}
#main{margin-left:320px}
#wrapall{padding-top:60px}

#page{padding:20px}
#menuToggle,#mobileMenuToggle{background:#FFF;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;font-size:40px;width:40px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;height:40px;line-height:40px;color:#344;border-radius:10px}
#mobileMenuToggle,#mobileLogo{vertical-align:middle;display:none;font-size:30px}
#menuToggle:hover{color:#FFF;background:#344}



@media screen and (max-width:1100px){header{padding:10px}
#headerLeft{width:auto}
#headerRight{width:60%}}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<header>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navbar" >
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
    
            
          </div>
    </div>
</header>

    <div id="main">
        <section id="page">
            <main>
                

                <article>
                    <h2>Illud mollis moderatius</h2>
                    <p>Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Ex ignota epicurei quo</h2>
                    <p>Quo debet vivendo ex. Qui ut admodum senserit partiendo. Id adipiscing disputando eam, sea id magna pertinax concludaturque. Ex ignota epicurei quo, his ex doctus delenit fabellas, erat timeam cotidieque sit in. Vel eu soleat voluptatibus, cum cu exerci mediocritatem. Malis legere at per, has brute putant animal et, in consul utamur usu.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>His at autem inani volutpat</h2>
                    <p>Te has amet modo perfecto, te eum mucius conclusionemque, mel te erat deterruisset. Duo ceteros phaedrum id, ornatus postulant in sea. His at autem inani volutpat. Tollit possit in pri, platonem persecuti ad vix, vel nisl albucius gloriatur no.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Stet facilis ius te</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum, integre urbanitas intellegam vix in.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Illud mollis moderatius</h2>
                    <p>Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Illud mollis moderatius</h2>
                    <p>Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Ex ignota epicurei quo</h2>
                    <p>Quo debet vivendo ex. Qui ut admodum senserit partiendo. Id adipiscing disputando eam, sea id magna pertinax concludaturque. Ex ignota epicurei quo, his ex doctus delenit fabellas, erat timeam cotidieque sit in. Vel eu soleat voluptatibus, cum cu exerci mediocritatem. Malis legere at per, has brute putant animal et, in consul utamur usu.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Illud mollis moderatius</h2>
                    <p>Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>His at autem inani volutpat</h2>
                    <p>Te has amet modo perfecto, te eum mucius conclusionemque, mel te erat deterruisset. Duo ceteros phaedrum id, ornatus postulant in sea. His at autem inani volutpat. Tollit possit in pri, platonem persecuti ad vix, vel nisl albucius gloriatur no.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Stet facilis ius te</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum, integre urbanitas intellegam vix in.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Illud mollis moderatius</h2>
                    <p>Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Ex ignota epicurei quo</h2>
                    <p>Quo debet vivendo ex. Qui ut admodum senserit partiendo. Id adipiscing disputando eam, sea id magna pertinax concludaturque. Ex ignota epicurei quo, his ex doctus delenit fabellas, erat timeam cotidieque sit in. Vel eu soleat voluptatibus, cum cu exerci mediocritatem. Malis legere at per, has brute putant animal et, in consul utamur usu.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>His at autem inani volutpat</h2>
                    <p>Te has amet modo perfecto, te eum mucius conclusionemque, mel te erat deterruisset. Duo ceteros phaedrum id, ornatus postulant in sea. His at autem inani volutpat. Tollit possit in pri, platonem persecuti ad vix, vel nisl albucius gloriatur no.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Stet facilis ius te</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum, integre urbanitas intellegam vix in.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Illud mollis moderatius</h2>
                    <p>Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>Ex ignota epicurei quo</h2>
                    <p>Quo debet vivendo ex. Qui ut admodum senserit partiendo. Id adipiscing disputando eam, sea id magna pertinax concludaturque. Ex ignota epicurei quo, his ex doctus delenit fabellas, erat timeam cotidieque sit in. Vel eu soleat voluptatibus, cum cu exerci mediocritatem. Malis legere at per, has brute putant animal et, in consul utamur usu.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h2>His at autem inani volutpat</h2>
                    <p>Te has amet modo perfecto, te eum mucius conclusionemque, mel te erat deterruisset. Duo ceteros phaedrum id, ornatus postulant in sea. His at autem inani volutpat. Tollit possit in pri, platonem persecuti ad vix, vel nisl albucius gloriatur no.</p>
                </article>

            

            </main>         
            <footer>
                
        </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487618/html5-css-sticky-header-with-logo-and-navigation here is quite familiar topic mayebe it would help :D

Comment: Plz include your code till now

Comment: What do you mean by "gradually goes up"? You should first properly understand what's your intented behavior before a technical solution can be applied. Do you mean that at 0% scroll the nav bar is at the bottom and at 100% scroll it's at the top? Or should it hit the top before reaching 100% scroll? If so, when?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `height:100vh;` in header class then `.header` will take the full screen height and the `#navbar` will be in bottom …
Or use `height:calc(100vh - 100px);` to make header take almost all height leaving 100px to navbar to render in it

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  height:100vh;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need any javascript to achieve that since you have position:sticky in css.

Here is an example of a navigation that both sticks to the bottom and top:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav>My nav</nav>
  <div class="contents">
    Contents<br>
    Contents<br>
    Contents<br>
    Contents<br>
    Contents<br>
    Contents
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  --nav-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
}
.contents {
  position: relative; /* remove to make contents go below navbar */
  top: -100vh; /* remove to make contents go below navbar */
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  height: 200vh; /* only to make contents block scrollable */
  line-height: 100px; /* only to make contents block scrollable */
  color: black;
}
nav {
  position:sticky; /* here is were the magic happens */
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: var(--nav-height);
  margin-top: calc(100vh - var(--nav-height)); /* ...and here */
}
```

https://codepen.io/nicolashervy/pen/xxgKpOM

Was that the look you were after?